# How to get a value from custom control in a broader control via binding in VM

Tags: xaml, binding, maui, attached-properties, bindable

MAUI.NET

I have a special picker for my own that I want to reuse in many places

```
<ContentView ...
         x:Class="XYZ.Views.ABCPicker"
         x:DataType="views:ABCPicker">
    <Grid>
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" SelectedItem="{Binding ChoosenDeviceTypeProperty}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

and its code behind with my AttachedProperty:

```
public partial class ABCPicker : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ChoosenDeviceTypeProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("ChoosenDeviceType", typeof(string), typeof(ABCPicker), "Detect by connect", BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public static string GetChoosenDeviceType(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (string)view.GetValue(ChoosenDeviceTypeProperty);
    }
    public static void SetChoosenDeviceType(BindableObject view, string value)
    {
        view.SetValue(ChoosenDeviceTypeProperty, value);
    }

    public ABCPicker()
    {
        this.BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I want to consume it in my broader control ViewModel

```
public class BroaderControlViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    ...
    private string myResult;
    public string MyResult
    {
        get { return myResult; }
        set { SetPropertyAndNotify(ref myResult, value); }
    }
    public ICommand MyCommand { private set; get; }
    public BroaderControlViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            // here I want the to get a choosen value to proceed with it after the user have choosen value in my special picker
        });
    }
}
```

with a view like below:

```
<ContentView ...
             x:Class="XYZ.Views.BroaderControlView"
             x:DataType="viewModels:BroaderControlViewModel">
    <VerticalStackLayout ...>
        <views:ABCPicker ChoosenDeviceType="{Binding MyResult, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Button Text="Connect" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

I tried different binding types, also with x:Reference this and also with normal binding properties - not attached ones.

How it should be matched?

Comment: In your code, the picker's selected item binds to the ChoosenDeviceTypePropert, and the ChoosenDeviceType binds to the MyResult. Did you try to test if the MyResult is the picker's selected item and process it in the MyCommand?

Comment: Why is it attached? Who else is defining it?